# php unixtime, time() and timezones

Tags: php

I run a few sites where I collect telemetry like temperatures, pressures, voltages etc. from a few countries around the world.

What would happen is that I would send a "valve close/open", or a "temp increase/decrease" command to one of these servers via automated e-mail. Once the e-mail is generated I get the current unix timestamp via `time()`. This serves 2 purposes. #1 it gives me the time when the e-mail was generated and it serves as a unique message ID.

This unix timestamp gets entered into an SQL database along with other information i.e which contoller issued the command, destination server etc.

Also, this unix timestamp (unique ID) gets sent with the e-mail to the destination server. Once the destination server gets the mail (via fetchmail and procmail) it does what it is instructed to do and it then sends a confirmation e-mail back to the main system. This e-mail that get's sent back carries with it the original unix timestamp (unique ID) and the time the destination server received the command (`$rx_time`) and the time the destination server issued the command (`$tx_time`) via `time()`. These servers run a local php script.

All is working well and I am happy. However, there are 32 destination servers that span 4 different time zones.

I do not want formatted dates sent in the e-mails eg: `2016-04-13 13:04:16` as that will clash with my procmail regexp recipes. I want a UTC +0 unix timestamp sent eg: `1234567890` and I will do the time conversion locally.

How would I go about setting the timezone to UTC +0 on all the 32 servers (in their local php script) and extract the unixtime from that?

Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Have all the local servers use the same timezone value for this part of their calculation. PHP can easily adjust timezones to run as if in another (ie non-local) timezone, as required

Comment: Unixtime is timezoneless and returns always the same value regardless of the time zone set.

Comment: As long as the time of the system PHP runs on is correct, there’s nothing to do. As a side note, I’d point out that one second is a relative eternity in computing terms in which *a lot* can happen; a Unix time stamp is hardly guaranteed to be *unique*. It really depends on your application whether it’s *unique enough* for your purpose.